# Changing focus with arrows and accessing children in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I have two questions according to kivy moving between components.

.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

Builder.load_file("keyboardreader.kv")

class MyTextInput(TextInput):
    focused=StringProperty('id1')
    def keyboard_on_key_down(self, window, keycode, text, modifiers):
        print(keycode, text, modifiers)
        if keycode[1] == "backspace":
            print("print backspace down", keycode)
        TextInput.keyboard_on_key_down(self, window, keycode, text, modifiers)
       
        if keycode[1]=="right":
            if int(self.focused[2])<5:
                focusedid=int(self.focused[2])+1
                self.focused="id"+str(focusedid)       
        if keycode[1]=="left":
            if int(self.focused[2])>1:
                focusedid=int(self.focused[2])-1
                self.focused="id"+str(focusedid)
        print(self.focused)
            
        

class MainScreen(Widget):
    pass
    
                 
class TestingappApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()
    
TestingappApp().run()
```

.kv

```
<MainScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        id: layout
        size: root.width,root.height
        MyTextInput:
            id: id1
        MyTextInput:
            id: id2
        MyTextInput:
            id: id3
        MyTextInput:
            id: id4
        MyTextInput:
            id: id5
```

I have few problems according to this code.

1. How can I access the element with certain id from the .kv file?
   I was always using the same form and it used to work, now it doesn't. For example, if I wanted to make a focus on element with id1, I was thinking about using

```
self.ids["id1"].focus=True
```

2. How can I access all children elements of an element? For example, I want the list of children of BoxLayout with id:layout, that there are id1,id2,...,id5 elements.

Comment: I realised that print(self.ids) returns empty dictionary, how do I fix that, because it is probably the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in order to access the children of a certain widget you can use the prop. `children` of that widget. But from the following...

> I want the list of children of BoxLayout with id:layout, that there are id1,id2,...,id5 elements.

it seems you want to pack all the children into something (here, in *'BoxLayout with id:layout'*). For this I modified your code in `kvlang` into this,

```py
<MainScreen>:
    CustomBox:
        id: layout
        size: root.size


<CustomBox@BoxLayout>:
    MyTextInput:
        id: id1
        focused: "id1"
    MyTextInput:
        id: id2
        focused: "id2"
    # etc.
```

This will enable you to access its children (i.e. `TextInput` objects) by `ids`. Also note that you have to initialize each `MyTextInput` instance with different `focused` property (in order to access them later).

Now keeping the method `keyboard_on_key_down` as it is, I bind the `focused` property to a callback function, say, `change_focus` (you can use `on_`prop method or take any other approaches) as,

```py
class MyTextInput(TextInput):
    focused=StringProperty('id1')
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bind(focused = self.change_focus) # Will call this function each time 'focused' changes.
    
    def change_focus(self, *args):
        id_val = self.focused
        app = App.get_running_app()
        if app.root is not None:
            # Now access the container.
            layout = app.root.ids["layout"]
            # Access the required widget and set its focus.
            layout.ids[id_val].focus = True

    def keyboard_on_key_down(self, window, keycode, text, modifiers):
        print(keycode, text, modifiers)
        ...
```

---

### Note:

This should make the method `keyboard_on_key_down` happen as expected but again you need to change some logic in it to get perfect result.

Comment: Hm, it seems like it fixed my problem only partially. While i click combination - right, left, right. It puts me on second, first and then on third container, not on second like it should. Where is the mistake, i cannot see it.

Comment: The values of focused aren't changing sometimes, but I don't know why does it happen.